# Spring Exception org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I'm beginner with rest service and spring and I'm facing this exception while trying to run my spring rest application this is the stackTrace:

```
Grave: StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facturesController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gestion.service.FactureService com.gestion.controllers.FacturesController.factureService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gestion.dao.FactureDao com.gestion.service.FactureServiceImpl.factureDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.gestion.dao.FactureDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gestion.service.FactureService com.gestion.controllers.FacturesController.factureService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gestion.dao.FactureDao com.gestion.service.FactureServiceImpl.factureDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.gestion.dao.FactureDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gestion.dao.FactureDao com.gestion.service.FactureServiceImpl.factureDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.gestion.dao.FactureDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gestion.dao.FactureDao com.gestion.service.FactureServiceImpl.factureDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.gestion.dao.FactureDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factureDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.gestion.dao.FactureDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.gestion.dao.FactureDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 57 more

    avr. 28, 2014 12:32:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    Grave: La servlet /gestionFacturation a généré une exception "load()"
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    avr. 28, 2014 12:32:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    avr. 28, 2014 12:32:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    avr. 28, 2014 12:32:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    Infos: Server startup in 6695 ms
```

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...../>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.service" /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.dao" /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.model" /> 

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" 
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="factureDAO" class="com.gestion.dao.FactureDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="factureService" class="com.gestion.service.FactureServiceImpl"></bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

rest-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans ......>

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.controllers" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.service" /> 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.dao" /> 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.gestion.model" /> 
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

my FactureController:

```
package com.gestion.controllers;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/factures")
public class FacturesController {
    @Autowired
    private FactureService factureService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listFactures(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("facture", new Facture());
        map.put("factureList", factureService.getAllFactures());
        return "factures";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addFacture(@ModelAttribute("facture") Facture facture,
            BindingResult result) {
        factureService.addFacture(facture);
        return "redirect:/factures/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{factureId}")
    public String deleteFacture(@PathVariable("factureId") Integer factureId) {
        factureService.deleteFacture(factureId);
        return "redirect:/factures/list";
    }

    public FactureService getFactureService() {
        return factureService;
    }

    public void setFactureService(FactureService factureService) {
        this.factureService = factureService;
    }

}
```

FactureServiceImpl:

```
package com.gestion.service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class FactureServiceImpl implements FactureService {

    @Autowired
    private FactureDao factureDao;

    @Override
    public void addFacture(Facture facture) {
        factureDao.addFacture(facture);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFacture(Integer numFacture) {
        factureDao.deleteFacture(numFacture);
    }

    @Override
    public Facture getFactureById(Integer numFacture) {
        return factureDao.getFactureById(numFacture);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Facture> getAllFactures() {
        return factureDao.getAllFactures();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFacture(Facture facture) {
        factureDao.updateFacture(facture);
    }

    public FactureDao getFactureDao() {
        return factureDao;
    }

    public void setFactureDao(FactureDao factureDao) {
        this.factureDao = factureDao;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide the package to scan to your application in xml like :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>        
    </bean>
```

Hibernate Configuration :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="pwd"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>
```

here com.domain is base package i which it will look for the autowired and have you created the interfaces for it and implemented all interfaces which you want to autowire ?

First of all create the Interfaces for the files which yiu want to autowire then implement them and call interfaces using `@Autowire` and not forget to put `@Service` on main class body.

Ok put this code of `TransactionManager` :

```
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Comment: i did that i think the probleme is about the declaration of sessionFactory that it's not found but i don't know why like you can see in my applicationContext File

Comment: Thanks for your answer i did that and i have now this exception:

    Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facturesController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gestion.service.FactureService